# Binding on framework vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here's a code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Vue</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root">
        <input v-model="message" placeholder="Msg">
        <p>Message you typed is: {{ message }}</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>

        new Vue({
            data: {
                el: '#root',
                message: ''
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why the binding doesn't work. I try from a video

```
https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/1 .
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vue instance is not connected to your element.

```
    <script>
            new Vue({
                el: '#root',
                data: {
                    message: 'Hello World!'
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`el` key should be on the object passed to the `Vue` constructor and not inside `data` object ([Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Declarative-Rendering))

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    message: ''
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <input v-model="message" placeholder="Msg">
  <p>Message you typed is: {{message}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new Vue({
    data: {
        el: '#root',
        message: ''
 }
});
```

should replace to

```
new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        message: ''
    }
});
```